# Web Audio API Firefox setValueCurveAtTime()

Tags: firefox, web-audio-api

I am crossfading some audio and I have a equal power curve stored in a table. I'm calling this function to start the fadeout. The fade parameter is a GainNode made with createGain()

fade.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(epCurveOut, context.currentTime, fadeTime);

In Chrome and Safari all goes well, but Firefox (v30) complains:
`SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified`

Instead of context.currentTime I've tried 0 and 0.01. Is this method not implemented maybe? If so how would I alternatively schedule a cosine equal power ramp over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug on our end indeed, I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1069825 to track this.

Comment: Aha thanks for clearing this up! Glad the try/catch is a valid workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox seems to give that error whenever it doesn't like the parameters to setValueCurveAtTime. For example, if epCurveOut is an empty Float32Array, or if there is already a parameter change scheduled at the same time. I suspect the latter, because Chrome doesn't throw an error under the same circumstances. For example:

```
curve = new Float32Array([0.5, 0.5]);
node.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(curve, 5, 1);
node.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(curve, 5, 1);
```

Firefox throws the error the second time. Chrome doesn't throw an error. If you call node.gain.cancelScheduledValues(5) in between the calls to setValueCurveAtTime, Firefox allows it.

EDIT: Oh, hmm, Chrome doesn't complain about an empty Float32Array either. Well, anyway, Firefox seems to be much less forgiving, and gives that error when the arguments' types are correct but the values aren't allowed.

Comment: The array is definitely not empty because I can hear it working in the other browsers. Also it's not the double scheduling I think, since I only retrigger the function after it has finished fading, manually. Now I simply put a try/catch over it and it seems to work! I do notice that if I trigger the function when it is still fading it's a no-op. But the syntax error happens every time and I don't know what's causing it yet...I'm reusing the same array for multiple layer fades simultaneously, but if FF doesn't allow that it wouldn't make much sense.