# Audio API setValueCurveAtTime() Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm loading a music file with a XMLHttpRequest, which I decode with 
`audioCtx.decodeAudioData(response)`.

Once done, I create an `AudioBufferSourceNode` which I connect through a `gainNode`, to `audioCtx.destination`

After that, I want the track to start slow, and increase the speed to 2x using setValueCurveAtTime:
`source.playbackRate.setValueCurveAtTime(new Float32Array([0, 2]), audioCtx.currentTime, 3);`

I expect the track to start with a playbackRate of 0 and increase to 2, over a time of 3 seconds. This works perfect in Chrome. But in Firefox the track starts with a playbackRate of 1, and after 3 seconds it's immediately switches to 2. So without transition.

Note that this is a different problem then [Web Audio API Firefox setValueCurveAtTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899432/web-audio-api-firefox-setvaluecurveattime)

Code:

```
let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let url  ='http://mdn.github.io/decode-audio-data/viper.ogg';

loadBuffer(url);

function loadBuffer(url) {
    console.log('loading buffer...');

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    request.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
        decodeAudioData(e.target.response);
    });

    request.send();
}

function decodeAudioData(response) {;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(response).then((decodedBuffer) => {
        console.log(`Decoding audio done`);

        let source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = decodedBuffer;

        let gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
        source.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

        source.start(0);
        source.playbackRate.setValueCurveAtTime(new Float32Array([0, 2]), audioCtx.currentTime, 3);
    });
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3uvaqukp/)**

The same happens when I replace this line:

```
source.playbackRate.setValueCurveAtTime(new Float32Array([0, 2]), audioCtx.currentTime, 3);
```

With this:

```
source.playbackRate.value = 1;
source.playbackRate.linearRampToValueAtTime(2, audioCtx.currentTime + 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some older implementations of the Web Audio API use nearest neighbour instead of linear interpolation when going through curve values. linearRampToValueAtTime requires two points at any time between which the current value can be calculated:

```
source.playbackRate.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, audioCtx.currentTime);
source.playbackRate.linearRampToValueAtTime(2, audioCtx.currentTime + 3);
```

To simplify things, you could instead use [setTargetAtTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/setTargetAtTime), using which you can define a transition time constant instead of having to add ramp points:

```
source.playbackRate.setTargetAtTime(2, audioCtx.currentTime, 3); // To 2, now, over 3 secs.
```

Comment: As for the playbackrate of 0, this should mimic a pause, as it does in Chrome.  For the older implementations: 'Chrome 46.0.2490 uses linear interpolation; earlier versions use nearest neighbor' (MDN) So I guess Firefox uses an earlier version too?

Comment: @Pimmol Yes, that's my assumption.